# When performing a tag-negation search, move the "not" before "tagged with"

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, search, wording

When we want to search for something which is not in a specific tag (or set of tags), the wording of the sidebar is as follows: ([sample search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bsupport%5D+unicorn))

> [image]

Or in words: (for sake of search)

> results found containing
>   [search term]
>
> tagged with
>   not [tag name]

That does not sound right. Better switch the "not" to be in front of "results found...":

> results found containing
>   [search term]
>
> not tagged with
>   [tag name]

Can this please be done?

Comment: I propose "tagged not with thy [tag name]".

Answer (score 4):

While I can live even with the current state of things, I still think it may be something worth considering.

There is a problem though: the search can contain both "positive" and "negative" tag filters at the same time ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=+Coin+-[support]+-pony+[discussion]+-[gravatar]+[fun]+unicorn+)). This result is something like:

> [image]

Notice how the terms filters part actually include a "and not containing" section. This means that the tags should ideally work the same way:

> results found containing
>   [search terms]
>
> and not containing
>   [negative search terms]
>
> tagged with
>   [search tags]
>
> and not tagged with
>   [negative search tags]

Basically it is the same ending result proposed by Shadow, but one should remember that positive tags search may be present too, resulting in the need to have two separate sections.

That said, I would leave to the developers the final decision to determine if such change is worth spending time on. I can't say if managing the split is going to be simple with the current implementation.

Comment: True, I did not fully consider all possible scenarios. Might change the request to apply only for cases when there is only tags negation used, which will make it more simple.

Comment: I *think* that if they are going to check that all tag search terms are negative, probably the effort to split the two section is fairly comparable. But only someone like Oded my answer. Turn on the (bat) mod signal.

Comment: lol, need to make something fitting. Though I fear that Oded is not assigned to search related bugs/features. :(